# matlab vector addition like multiplication, without for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, multiplication, addition

Normally when one adds two vectors this is what happens

```
[1 4] + [2 5]  = [3 9]
```

I want it to do this:

```
[1 4] + [2 5]  =  3  6
                  6  9
```

So basically addition like how multiplication happens. But without using for-loops.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is with [meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html).

```
x = [1 4];
y = [2 5];
[a, b] = meshgrid(y,x);
a + b
```

Comment: Note that while this works perfectly, if `x` and `y` are large, then @Jonas' solution is better because it doesn't replicate the arrays.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the poster cases for using [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
x = [1 4];
y = [2 5];
bsxfun(@plus,x,y')
```